# Python click package no such option error when option is defined

Tags: python

Attempt to run test program (shown later below) results in error:

> $ python -m test test2 --all
>
> test #2 True
>
> Usage: **main**.py [OPTIONS]
>
> Try "**main**.py --help" for help.
>
> Error: no such option: --all

However, running test program with click "--help" option clearly shows that "-all" is an available option on the test2 command.

> $ python -m test test2 --help
>
> Usage: **main**.py test2 [OPTIONS]
>
> Options:
>     --all
>     --help  Show this message and exit.

```
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
def test1():
    print("test #1")

@cli.command()
@click.option("--all", is_flag=True)
def test2(all):
    print("test #2", all)
    if all:
        test1()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Answer (score 4):

After some basic research and a bunch of print statements, finally realized that having command "test2" call command "test1" was not a good idea.  Apparently when the test1() call happens, click's decorators assist by passing in the options and the "test1" command does not recognize the "--all" option, hence the error.

Better way to set up code is to pull out the stuff that test1() does, and put into a helper like _test1() and use that in both test1() and test2():

```
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
def test1():
    print("test #1")

@cli.command()
@click.option("--all", is_flag=True)
def test2(all):
    print("test #2", all)
    if all:
        _test1()

def _test1():
    """ worker for test1 """
    print("test #1")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Comment: What if `test1()` has its own `@cli.command()` and `click.option()`s?